# COMPLUS_LoaderOptimization not working in Azure app service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I tried setting COMPLUS_LoaderOptimization environment variable to 1 in my azure app service using the extensions. As I check the process explorer in kudu, COMPLUS_LoaderOptimization was set to 1 but it is still not working as expected that loads the assemblies in non-domain neutral. Is this supported in azure app service?

Comment: This is already fix for full framework in azure app services, COMPLUS_LoaderOptimization for dynamic assembly loading but it has a problem for IIS user profile. In this case for basic azure service plan we can use WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE.

Answer (score 0):

This is already fixed for full framework in azure app services, COMPLUS_LoaderOptimization works to load the assemblies in non-domain neutral for dynamic assembly loading but it has a problem for IIS user profile. In this case for basic azure service plan, we can use WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE.

Comment: For me things did't work even after setting `WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE` to 1 when my app service plan was using `Free` tier. It started to work after I upgraded it to `S1` tier.